# How to eagerload 2 different relation in 1 table Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have a problem to eagerload 2 relation in 1 table in laravel 9. i have table called photos have relation with users and photo_categories. so what i want to achieve is to load user and categories in same time.also im already declare the relation at the model.
what i already try is like code bellow

```
$photos = Photo::with('user','photoCategory')->where('id',$request->id)->first(); //at show method

$photos = new PhotoCollection(Photo::with('user','photoCategories')->OrderByDesc('id')->paginate(10));//at index method
```

my relation at Photo Model

```
public function user(){
 return $this->BelongsTo(User::class);
}
public function photoCategory(){
 return $this->HasMany(FotoCategory::class);
}
```

my relation at user model

```
public function photo(){
 return $this->HasMany(PhotoCategory::class);
}
```

my relation at user photoCategory model

```
public function photo(){
 return $this->BelongsTo(Photo::class);
}
```

please help me to figure out the problems
thankyou in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a typo in your code where you are calling photoCategories instead of photoCategory in the with method when eager loading the photoCategory relation.

Try updating your code like this:

```
$photos = Photo::with('user', 'photoCategory')->where('id', $request->id)->first(); //at show method

$photos = new PhotoCollection(Photo::with('user', 'photoCategory')->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(10)); //at index method
```

Also, make sure that your PhotoCategory model has a belongsTo relationship to Photo model, like this:

```
public function photo(){
    return $this->belongsTo(Photo::class);
}
```

Comment: yep there is a typo thx

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you have issues with your Photo model. The photoCategory method should be  BelongsTo relationship:

```html
public function photoCategory()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(PhotoCategory::class);
}
```

In user model :

```html
public function photos()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Photo::class);
}
```

Here is final output relationship data :

```html
$photos = Photo::with('user', 'photoCategory')->where('id', $request->id)->first();

$photos = new PhotoCollection(Photo::with('user', 'photoCategory')->orderByDesc('id')->paginate(10));
```

Hope this will help you.